# Does Win-Acme / LetsEncrypt renew existing certificates or replace them?

Tags: ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

I'm at the initial stages of considering the use of LetsEncrypt certificates for my Windows radius server. I don't see any purpose in the purchase and renewal process every year for what it is used for.

My question is this...Using Win-Acme to automatically renew the certificates, does it extend/renew the existing certificate, or does it create a new certificate and remove the old?

In my Radius configuration I have to select the certificates to use for authentication. I'm concerned that the renewal process will generate a new certificate which will not be assigned on the Radius server, and authentication will fail. I'm assuming if this is the case, the next step would be to setup a script to possibly handle the Radius reconfiguration because I do not think Win-Acme will do it.

Answer (score 1):

After a quick view into [the documentation](https://www.win-acme.com/) it looks like the behaviour depends on what you select to store the certificates.

For example, for the [windows certificate store](https://www.win-acme.com/reference/plugins/store/certificatestore) there is a flag `--keepexisting` which indicates that by default the old certificate is removed on renewal.

For the other storage options, there is nothing mentioned explicitly, but there is an option [`DeleteStaleFiles`](https://www.win-acme.com/reference/settings), which defaults to `false`. If enabled, old files are removed from the certificate store path after 120 days. This indicates that by default old certificate files are kept (if you select files as the storage option).